# Dividing circle into six equal parts and know the coordinates of each diving point ...

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a circle who center $(0, 0)$ and radius $100$ are known. That circle is divided into $6$ equal parts. I want to know the coordinates of all six points on the circle that divides it into $6$ parts. Can anyone please tell me the formula for this as I need to do this in a javscript code.

Also give a  formula for doing the same thing with ellipse given the same data, center $(0, 0)$, $x$-radius and $y$-radius are known.

Comment: added the ellipse ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's divided into 6 equal sectors, then you can calculate the angle $\theta$ (in radians) of each of the lines to the positive $x$-axis simply by doing:

$$\theta_{n}=\frac{2n\pi}{6}=\frac{n\pi}{3},\qquad\text{where }n=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$$

To calculate the cartesian co-ordinates of the points, all you now need to do is convert the polar form $100\angle\theta_{n}$:

$$x_{n}=100\cdot\cos{\theta_{n}} \\ y_{n}=100\cdot\sin{\theta_{n}}$$

---

This can of course be extended to any number $k$ of equal area sectors of a circle of origin $(x_{0},y_{0})$ and radius $r$ using:

$$\theta_{n}(k)=\frac{2n\pi}{k},\qquad \text{where }n=\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$$

Then, converting from polar co-ordinates and translating: $$x_{n}=r\cdot\cos{(\theta_{n}(k))}+x_{0} \\ y_{n}=r\cdot\sin{(\theta_{n}(k))}+y_{0}$$

Comment: what changes are needed if am calculating with respect to y axis

Comment: @Gaurav Sachdeva If I understand you correctly, exchange cos' and sin's.

Comment: @Alex, wat i meant was, instead of calculating angles to positve x-axis, i am calculating angle to positive-y axis...so the above change will do ??

Comment: @Gaurav Sachdeva So, 0 = top, 90 = left, 180 = bottom and 270 = right?

Comment: yes..thats right

Comment: @GauravSachdeva to get the same points as though you were calculating relative to the $x$-axis, you displace each angle by $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ (which can be done simply by exchanging $\sin$ for $\cos$ and vice versa). However, if you just want *some* set of points which you can use to divide the circle into $k$ parts, then it makes no difference if you use the formula here with those angles or displace all the angles by any constant.

Comment: @Shaktal displace each angle by $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ (I assume you meant 2) isn't the same as changing sin and cos. The latter will reflect along y = x.

Comment: thanks shaktal, you solved my problem....really appreciate ur effort to write a generalised case..thanks :)

Comment: @Shaktal... i need a little more help, if you could do. I need to apply the same thing for the ellipse as well. Same i have the center and x-radius and y-radius and need to divide it into 6 parts, measuring angle along the x-axis..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here, the very generalized formula :) (including ellipse)

$r_x$ and $r_y$ being the radius on the x-axis and y-axis respectively.
$\alpha$ is the angle of the rotation of all points. i.e. $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}$ would rotate all points counter-clockwise by 90 degrees.
$M_x$ and $M_y$ are the center coordinates.
And finally, $n$ is the number of segments.

$$\theta = \frac{2\pi}{n}\cdot k+\alpha\qquad \text{,where }k\in \left \{ 0,1,2,...,n-1\right \}$$
$$\text{Now,}\ x = M_x + r_x\cdot\cos(\theta)\text{ and }y=M_y + r_y\cdot\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: thanks alex for the answer... :)

Comment: thankyou so much alex....you made my day :)

Comment: Let's say I want my ellipse in 7 segments and I'm calculating the 2nd segment point. Then in that case n = 2, but what should k be in that case?

Comment: Ok. I've figured : n = Total Number of Segments. k = The Current Segment you want to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

use phythogorus theorem by the ratio of  triangle $1:2:\sqrt3$ ,and add the radius.
then you can  acheive thee co ordinates,,,first draw rough diagram of circle ,and divide in to three equaal parts ,then join the points,,you will see a triangle of equal sides,then again draw a half triangle from the centre,,now use phythogorus theorem .by above ratio ,,ahhhh
you have got the co ordinates ..ok